# Scraping links in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.forever21.com/IN/Product/Category.aspx? br=f21&category=top&pagesize=100&page=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
for link in links:
   if "BR=LOVE" in str(link):
      link = str(link)
      result = link[9:124]
      #if "VariantID=" in result:
       print((result))
```

The above code returns a list of links from forever21.com. But the problem is instead of :

```
http://www.forever21.com/IN/Product/Product.aspx?BR=LOVE21&Category=top&ProductID=2000183855&VariantID=
```

it returns

```
http://www.forever21.com/IN/Product/Product.aspx?BR=LOVE21&amp:Category=top&amp:ProductID=2000183855&amp:VariantID=
```

Notice it automatically replaces `&` with `&amp:` in every link. Don't know why.

Kindly let me know why it happens?

Comment: Are you sure that it’s `&amp:` and not `&amp;` (with a semi-colon)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML (and XML), an ampersand, `&` is used to delimit the beginning of **HTML entities**, e.g., a literal less-than symbol, `<` is represented as `&lt;`. If the HTML entity isn’t used, the HTML parser would interpret the less-than symbol as the beginning of a *HTML tag*.

Since an ampersand is used to denote the beginning of a HTML entity, a literal `&` is itself represented by `&amp;`.  A bare ampersand (`&` that isn’t denoting that start of an HTML entity) is not valid HTML even if most web browsers work around such instances of invalid HTML by treating the `&` as literal.

In contrast, the goal of BeautifulSoup is to convert badly written invalid HTML into *valid* HTML so it fixes the input HTML by converting bare ampersands to `&amp;`.  This is [documented behaviour](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters):

> By default, the only characters that are escaped upon output are bare
>   ampersands and angle brackets. These get turned into “&”, “<”, and
>   “>”, so that Beautiful Soup doesn’t inadvertently generate invalid HTML
>   or XML:
>
> ```
> soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&bar=val2">A link</a>')
> soup.a
> # <a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&amp;bar=val2">A link</a>
> ```

Having valid HTML is not a problem. Naturally, all HTTP user agents will do the right thing with the converted URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior - from the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters):

> By default, the only characters that are escaped upon output are **bare
>   ampersands** and angle brackets. These get turned into “`&amp;`”, “`&lt;`”,
>   and “`&gt;`”, so that Beautiful Soup doesn’t inadvertently generate
>   invalid HTML or XML

**Possible Solutions**:

> can change this behavior by providing a value for the formatter
>   argument to `prettify()`, `encode()`, or `decode()`

Or, Simply substitute it (not an elegant solution):

```
result = link[9:124]
result = re.sub(r'&amp;', r'&', result)
print((result)
```

)

**Result**:

```
http://www.forever21.com/IN/Product/Product.aspxBR=LOVE21&Category=top&ProductID=2000183855&VariantID=
```